# HashCode and Equals in Java

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I understand the basic concept of overriding hashcode and equals in a class , But can anyone give me an example (code) where the equals will fail only because hashcode was not overridden ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't have that kind of code. equals cannot fail because hashcode is not overridden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that `equals` itself will fail - it's that anything that relies on the contract of `hashCode` and its relationship to `equals` could fail. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.*;

final class Person {
    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        // TODO: Nullity prohibition
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || other.getClass() != Person.class) {
            return false;
        }
        return name.equals(((Person)other).name);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Person p1 = new Person("Jon");
        Person p2 = new Person("Jon");
        System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // true

        Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        System.out.println(people.size()); // 2!
    }
}
```

`HashSet` assumes that because `p1.hashCode()` isn't the same as `p2.hashCode()`, the two elements must be unequal, so can both be in the set. That wouldn't happen if `hashCode()` were appropriately overridden.

Likewise you could have (with the same `Person` class);

```
Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<Person, String>();
map.put(p1, "foo");
System.out.println(map.get(p2)); // null
```

This *would* print out "foo" if the two objects returned equal hash codes, as they're meant to - but again, because they don't, the `HashMap` thinks there's no match.

[Eric Lippert's blog post on `GetHashCode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) is a good introduction to this - it's C#-based, but it applies equally to Java.

Answer (score 0):

If your equals is failing it is because you implemented equals wrong.

Here is how to do it correctly:
the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/1426079) to [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/418556).

but, just for fun here is an example of an equals method that will fail if hashcode is not overridden:

```
//NEVER DO THIS
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    ThisObject obj = (ThisObject)o;
    return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
}
```